# Gradle 2.6 не резолвит зависимость с bintray

Tags: java, bash, gradle

Собираю все достаточно стандартно:

```
$ gradle clean test war -b build.gradle
```

Gradle ругается так:

```
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find mvc-tools.jar (net.virtalab:mvc-tools:2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
     http://dl.bintray.com/virtalab/maven/net/virtalab/mvc-tools/2.1/mvc-tools-2.1.jar
```

Хотя JAR по данному урлу есть:

```
$ wget http://dl.bintray.com/virtalab/maven/net/virtalab/mvc-tools/2.1/mvc-tools-2.1.jar
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27222 (27K) [application/java-archive]
...
$ file mvc-tools-2.1.jar
mvc-tools-2.1.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Что уже пытался?

- Запускать с debug (так и не понял проблему)
- rm -rf .gradle

Как можно поробороть gradle?

Comment: можете приложить свой build.gradle?

Comment: Может быть в конфигурации gradle указан доступ к интернету через прокси, а прокси не доступен?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась кардинальным удалением директории `~/.gradle`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275984/gradle-2-6-doesnt-resolve-dependency-from-bintray